# Zelig R Cluster Standard Errors Function No Effect

Tags: r, regression, simulation, r-zelig

Zelig does not appear to be doing anything when provided information on clusters. Am I doing something wrong? I really appreciate the ease with which this package generates predicted values for changes in a single variable--very useful for getting a sense of the substantive effect of one of my variables.

Here is a MWE:

```
library(Zelig)
data(bivariate)
summary(m_cluster <- zelig(formula=y1 ~ x1, data=bivariate, cluster="x4", "logit"))
summary(m_noCluster <- zelig(formula=y1 ~ x1, data=bivariate, "logit"))
```

It does not seem to matter if I make the cluster variable a factor, either:

```
summary(zelig(formula=y1 ~ x1, data=bivariate, cluster=as.factor(bivariate$x4), "logit"))
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I have contacted developers but no answer yet. Instead, I use rms package.